# compact set definition

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I think i don't really understand the definition of a compact set. The definition for metric spaces (say $(P,\rho)$) that I read is that:

We call $M\subset P$ compact in $(P,\rho)$ if from its every open cover we can select finite sub-cover.

The definition of a cover:

We call the system of sets $\{M_\alpha\}$ cover of $M$ if $M = \cup_{\alpha}M_\alpha$. If all $M_\alpha$ are open, we call the cover open cover.

Now, since $M\subset M$, then if $M$ is open, it has to be compact as it covers itself. So there is something missing in my definitions of cover or compactness.

Comment: It's not "there is an open cover with a finite subcover", it's "for ANY open cover there's a finite subcover", so just checking {M} is not enough. Also note that a subcover is a set of sets (a subset of the cover, which is also a set of sets), not a set of points.

Comment: Double-check that "open cover" is defined in your text as $M = \cup_{\alpha}M_\alpha$ with an equals sign.  It's more generally defined as $M \subseteq \cup_{\alpha}M_\alpha$, so that the determination of compactness can be done entirely in $P$ (as opposed to in a subspace topology)